# Get first item in a json list with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json data with this structure in Nodejs

```
{ 
    ids: 
        [ 
            'Deploy:1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce',
            'Deploy:f899e1e4-d512-469d-979c-835e98ced8b7',
            'Deploy:02f530d3-9727-4894-a1be-c2f90c430251',
            'Deploy:254f10bd-374a-41c8-a0ca-7a5ba37e7d2e',
            'Deploy:511f878b-a9e9-4c6b-bbf8-1024131fcc86'
        ] 
}
```

How can I get the first value for "Deploy" key? Preferably JS code not extra libraries.

So for example, I want to get this value `1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce` which is the first entry.

Comment: by that do you mean 'Deploy:1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce' or '1426ba8e' ?

Comment: Could you provide an example of an expecting result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var firstDeployValue = data.ids[0].split(':')[1];` should give you `1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce` If you want `Deploy` in there as well remove the split bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with `split`;

```js
const data = {
  ids: [
    'Deploy:1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce',
    'Deploy:f899e1e4-d512-469d-979c-835e98ced8b7',
    'Deploy:02f530d3-9727-4894-a1be-c2f90c430251',
    'Deploy:254f10bd-374a-41c8-a0ca-7a5ba37e7d2e',
    'Deploy:511f878b-a9e9-4c6b-bbf8-1024131fcc86'
  ]
};

const result = data.ids[0].split(':')[1];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just assign it to an object, like

```
jsonObj = { 
ids: 
    [ 
        'Deploy:1426ba8e-5d9d-4572-888d-2265ae7474ce',
        'Deploy:f899e1e4-d512-469d-979c-835e98ced8b7',
        'Deploy:02f530d3-9727-4894-a1be-c2f90c430251',
        'Deploy:254f10bd-374a-41c8-a0ca-7a5ba37e7d2e',
        'Deploy:511f878b-a9e9-4c6b-bbf8-1024131fcc86'
    ] 
}
```

and then just access it using jsonObj.ids[0].match(regexpattern)